# Initializing and updating a reactive (data.table) in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

Is there any possibility to inialize a reactive in shiny? 
I want to a have a reactive data.table. Part of this data.table does not change, so I would not need to reinitialize it every time input changes, but would only need to update columns "original_values" and "working_values".

Is this possible? Or is this a [case for better using reactiveValues() with observe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436713/r-shiny-reactivevalues-vs-reactive), even though I [calculate values here and do not have sideeffects](https://rpubs.com/The_Great_White_Bryan/150250)?

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1",min = 0.1, max = 1, value = 0.4, step = 0.05),
      sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2",min = 0.1, max = 1, value = 0.4, step = 0.05),                               
      sliderInput("slider3", "Slider 3",min = 100, max = 20000, value = 5000, step= 200)
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tableOut")

    )

  ))

  server <- function(input, output, session){
    rv_dtWeights <- reactive({

      #initalization - can this be put somewhere else?
      ret <- data.table(slider_names= c("slider1","slider2", "slider3"), 
                        some_grouping_information=c("A", "A", "B") )

      #actual reactive
      ret[,original_values :=c(input$slider1,input$slider2,input$slider3)]
      ret[,working_values:=sum(original_values), by=some_grouping_information]

    })

    output$tableOut<- renderTable(rv_dtWeights())

  }
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there global variables in R Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333399/are-there-global-variables-in-r-shiny)

Comment: @JulienNavarre: No, it is not. The similarity is the answer: I can use a data.table as a global variable, and can extend it with a reactive. But that is only the answer.

Comment: Just in case someone comes here wondering why reactivity does not work with data.table (As I did when posting this question): See https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1017 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536940/shiny-reactivity-fails-with-data-tables

Comment: The := in the data.table package is out-dated and can be very confusing to R beginners when it is presented together with the complexity of Shiny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put it outside of the `reactive`, and in the `server` (or outside of the `server`, for some more info on the differences, see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)). An example is given below, where the `data.table` is only initialized once when the user opens the app.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1",min = 0.1, max = 1, value = 0.4, step = 0.05),
      sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2",min = 0.1, max = 1, value = 0.4, step = 0.05),                               
      sliderInput("slider3", "Slider 3",min = 100, max = 20000, value = 5000, step= 200)
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tableOut")

    )

  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  #initalization - can this be put somewhere else?
  ret <- data.table(slider_names= c("slider1","slider2", "slider3"), 
                    some_grouping_information=c("A", "A", "B") )


  rv_dtWeights <- reactive({
    #actual reactive
    ret[,original_values :=c(input$slider1,input$slider2,input$slider3)]
    ret[,working_values:=sum(original_values), by=some_grouping_information]

  })

  output$tableOut<- renderTable(rv_dtWeights())

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```